# Fading in and out the lines of this plexus animation as they're joined and deleted

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I've followed this tutorial to create a plexus animation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYgRdPR65o8&ab_channel=DeayanStudios

It works really well, the only issue I have is I want the lines to fade in and out as they come closer/move further away. Currently they snap in and out of existence.

I'm a bit of a geo-nodes noob so I haven't made any progress but I was wondering if maybe capturing the distance and feeding that into the shader might work?

Thanks for any and all suggestions :)

I'll post my .blend in the comments with blend-exchange (havent used it before so hopefully it works)

[image]

Comment: Here's the .blend, thanks again!

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=6o8d96bb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/6o8d96bb/)

Comment: No need to post it in the comments, as the instructions say: "Add this text into your post". I took the freedom to edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've solved it well enough for my purposes.
Measured the distance between points, sent that to the output of the geometry nodes then used an attribute node in the shader to reference the distance which controls alpha and emission strength.

[image][image]
[image]